# Does .data goes to stack or heap in masm?

Tags: memory, memory-management, assembly, masm, masm32

When you declare variables in the .data segment in MASM, where are those vars allocated? In the stack or in the heap memory? And what about the ".data?" segment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither, they are allocated statically instead.